# How to get count of selected entries from Compact Edition SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

There is the following code:

```
private void FormViewing_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenConnection();
    FillFields();
}

private void OpenConnection()
{
    connectionString = string.Format("DataSource=\"{0}\"; Password=\"{1}\"", dbPath, Constants.DB_PASSWORD);
    connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
}

private void FillFields()
{
    string sql = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0})", 
        Constants.TABLE_NAME);
    SqlCeCommand selectCommand = new SqlCeCommand(sql, connection);
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(selectCommand.ExecuteScalar());
    }
    catch (Exception exeption)
    {
        this.Text = exeption.Message;
    }
}
```

I need to get count of entries, but I get the exception:

> *There was an error parsing the query*

I don't understand what a mistake I made. Please, describe a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be the right parenthesis ")" in:

```
string sql = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0})"
```